# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.duty' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `duty` AS `main_table

Tags: magento-1.9

**There has been an error processing your request**

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.duty' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `duty` AS `main_table`

Trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(522): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Data\Collection\Db.php(569): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(550): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Freight\Duty\Block\Adminhtml\Duty\Grid.php(19): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(643): Freight_Duty_Block_Adminhtml_Duty_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php(649): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\grid\container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\\defau...')
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\\defau...')
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#36 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#37 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#38 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Freight\Duty\controllers\Adminhtml\DutyController.php(16): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#39 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Freight_Duty_Adminhtml_DutyController->indexAction()
#40 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#41 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#42 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#43 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#44 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#45 {main}
```

**mysql-install-0.1.0.php**

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$sql=<<<SQLTEXT
create table duty (duty_id int not null auto_increment, title varchar(100), content text(200), status varchar(100),primary key(duty_id));

SQLTEXT;

$installer->run($sql);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Someone can help to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
    CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('duty')}` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `content` text(200),
      `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;      
");


$installer->endSetup();
```